# Drawing 3 circle (diagram) in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am relatively new to diagram in latex.

Basically, I want to draw a diagram as shown below. It does not be exact same, but around that content.

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (2,2) circle (3cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)%E2%80%94Basic_Drawing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of this is difficult and most of the things have already been done somewhere. So all you need to do is to google and to patch the pieces from here and there together. The ring shading is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82432), the `fancy arrow` is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500018) and the rest is from the pgf manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc} 
\makeatletter%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82432
\pgfdeclareradialshading[tikz@ball]{ring}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}%
{rgb(0cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.719cm)=(1,1,1);
rgb(0.72cm)=(1,1,1);
color(0.9cm)=(tikz@ball!60)}
\tikzoption{ring color}{\pgfutil@colorlet{tikz@ball}{#1}\def\tikz@shading{ring}\tikz@addmode{\tikz@mode@shadetrue}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fancy arrow/.style={decorate,decoration={ % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500018
 show path construction, 
 curveto code={ 
 \draw[top color=blue!30,bottom color=blue] 
 let \p1=($(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$) in 
 [/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\mysign}{sign(\x1)}] 
 ([yshift=-3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls 
 ([yshift=-3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and ([yshift=-3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) 
 ..([yshift=-3.5pt,xshift=\mysign*3pt]\tikzinputsegmentlast) 
 -- ([yshift=-3.5pt,xshift=\mysign*3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentlast) 
 -- ([yshift=-5.5pt,xshift=\mysign*3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentlast) 
 -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast) 
 -- ([yshift=5.5pt,xshift=\mysign*3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentlast) 
 -- ([yshift=3.5pt,xshift=\mysign*3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentlast) 
 .. controls 
 ([yshift=3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) and ([yshift=3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) 
 .. ([yshift=3.5pt]\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- cycle;}}},
 pics/fancy circle/.style={code={
 \path[even odd rule,fill=#1!60,path picture={
 \draw[line width=6mm,#1!20] ([yshift=3mm]path picture bounding box.west)
 to[out=-20,in=-120] ([xshift=5mm]path picture bounding box.north);
 }]  
 circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fancy circle/radius}] 
 circle[radius=0.8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fancy circle/radius}];
 \path[even odd rule,ring color=#1] 
  circle[radius=0.8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fancy circle/radius}]
  circle[radius=0.8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fancy circle/radius}-1mm];}},
 fancy circle/radius/.initial=1.55cm,
 pics/arr/.style={code={\draw[#1,top color=#1!20,bottom color=#1]
 (45:0.5) -- ++ (0.3,0) -- ++ (-45:0.5) -- ++(-135:0.5) --++ (-0.3,0)
 -- ++ (45:0.5) -- cycle;}}] 
%
 \path(-4,0) pic{fancy circle=blue} node[font=\large\sffamily]{AAA} 
  (-2.7,0) pic{arr=blue}
  (0,0) pic{fancy circle=purple} node[font=\sffamily]{Transformation} 
  (1.3,0) pic{arr=purple}
  (4,0) pic{fancy circle=orange} node[font=\large\sffamily]{AAA} ;
 \path (0,-2.5) node[top color=white,bottom color=green!30,rounded
  corners=3pt,draw=green!40,font=\sffamily\Large,minimum height=1cm,
  minimum width=2cm](H) {HUMAN};
 \draw[fancy arrow] (H.east) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=1.5]++(0,1);
 \draw[fancy arrow] ([yshift=1cm]H.west)
  to[out=180,in=180,looseness=1.5] (H.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you cancel the shading in the circle? Thanks

Comment: How can add into my document file? It seemed like standalone. I am using `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}`

Comment: @aan Just replace `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}` by `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} \usepackage{tikz}`. To remove the shading of the circles, remove `\path[even odd rule,ring color=#1] 
  circle[radius=0.8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fancy circle/radius}]
  circle[radius=0.8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fancy circle/radius}-1mm];`.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Which part to remove the 2 white part in the circle? The `white box` in the ring of the circle?

Comment: @aan It is `,path picture={
 \draw[line width=6mm,#1!20] ([yshift=3mm]path picture bounding box.west)
 to[out=-20,in=-120] ([xshift=5mm]path picture bounding box.north);
 }`. If you just want to draw a node in a circle, say `\node[circle,draw,line width=5mm,minimum size=3.2cm]{blabla} at (<x>,<y>);`.

Comment: Thanks, where can i put the label of this figure? will it be `\caption{This is a black box}
    \label{fig:fig_1} \end{tikzpicture}` But not working

Comment: @aan You need to add `\begin{figure}` before `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\caption{This is a black box} \label{fig:fig_1}\end{figure}` **after** `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: it is an awesome diagram, but how can I jump the line of the text inside the circles? Thanks.

Comment: @JulioCésarCruzMonterrosas Add e.g. `align=center` to the options of the corresponding `node`s. Notice also that it is not very difficult to make the circles adjust to the sizes of the texts, but this deserves a new question.